# ODP.NET Implement Cursor for SELECT statement

Tags: c#, .net, oracle-sqldeveloper, odp.net, odp

How can I implement a simple cursor fetch on a basic `SELECT statement like 'SELECT * FROM Employees'` using ODP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's quite straightforward.

First create `OracleConnection` class like this

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString);

con.Open();  //opens connection
```

Then you define and `OracleCommand` instance first by passing either raw query/stored procedure as first argument like

So in your particular case it would be `OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", con`

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(<query>/<stored proc>, con))
{    
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  //in case of stored proc
cmd.BindByName = true;

OracleDataReader reader;
try
  {
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("field: {0}", reader.GetDecimal(0));  
    }    
  }
catch (OracleException e)
  {
  foreach (OracleError err in e.Errors)
    {
       //print errors         
     }
   }
 con.Close(); 
 con.Dispose();
}
}
```

Here is the example http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-refcursors-092375.html